# Magento1 admin order status update 404 error page

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, error, sales-order, order-grid

I have Magento1 website but when Admin panel Order Grid select any order  then submit that order status update click on submit button show second page 404 error come. So solution please this problem.

I have given screen short.

[image]
[image]

Second page link like.

Main website url `/index.php/orderstatus/adminhtml_orderstatus/massOrderStatus/`

Below error show.

`Sorry, 404 Page not found.`

It looks like you may have taken a wrong turn and gone off the trail.

Don't worry. It happens to the best of us.

Here is a little map that might help you get back on track.

Comment: This action "update order status" does not belong to Magento core, it comes from a third-party extension.

Please provide the name or source code for the extension, or contact the extension provider.

Comment: you need to compaitible that third party extension to suppee 6788